# Parse.com modifying an object in local database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an android application using parse.com. In offline mode I use

```
Item item = new Item();
item.saveEventually()
```

Item extends ParseObject to create the object in the local store.

Still in offline mode I can query all the item records and the offline created records show up. Now I want to delete one of the records created offline. Is there a way to do it? As far as I can see that the record does not have any objectId at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `item.deleteEventually()` to delete the item locally and also on parse.com when the network is established.

Comment: How do I get the reference to item in another fragment or activity?

Comment: You save item in an array or any other collection and then pin them using a group id. You can retrieve this collection elsewhere using the group id and then use `deleteEventually` to delete the object.